# Where would one find thermal heat sink cases?

Tags: heatsink

I am looking for a case that would work well as a heat sink. Thinking  that something like a car amplifier case? Anyone know where one could find cases like this? Would be using it to house H-Bridges and fill it with thermal conductive epoxy to water proof it....

Comment: It would be a much cheaper idea to screw the power components to the case (e.g. TO-220's) then use some arbitrary potting compound and not worry about it having excellent thermal properties.

Comment: @mikeselectricstuff: This is a better kind of link for that message: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=heatsink+box :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of [these](http://www.lincolnbinns.com/e-case.htm) extruded aluminium ones?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those commercial cases might work, but you'll note that a car amplifier has many, large fins - this dramatically increases the surface area. Those commercial boxes just have some beauty stripes. Also don't forget the volume calculation: I don't know how much thermally conductive epoxy costs, but even, say, a 1 by 3 by 6 inch box has a fair amount of internal volume.

What you also could do is to salvage the heat sinks from the inside on an old PC power supply. These come with screws and insulators and are pretty big in terms of surface area. You might be able to bolt these to the outside of an otherwise flat box (you want to use gap filler between them) to heat sink it. Alternatively, just screw your high temp components to them and the encapsulate over them with your epoxy.

If you're in an environment that can tolerate it, using salvaged heat sinks and salvaged fans inside a salvaged power supply enclosure would likely work well.